# Can FullCalender show events in the month view based on the Start and End time not date?

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

In FullCalendar, in Month view, when I add an event, if the duration of the event is less than 24 hours, then FullCalendar shows it as a dot. If the duration is more than 24 hours, then it is shown as a bar. Now what I want to achive is always showing all the events as a bar and the length of the bar respective to the duration. For exmaple if Start is 10:00AM and end is 14:00PM, I want to have a bar which does not occupay the whole day, but respectivly form 10:00 to 14:00 (check the image).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to show all events as a bar, by changing the [eventDisplay](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDisplay) setting to

```
eventDisplay: "block"
```

But you cannot adjust the duration, because the month view is not a time-aware view - the smallest duration of time it understands is 1 day.

Comment: Yes, the option you mention change the dot presentation to the bar presentation. So I was wondering if there is any way to implement moth view which is time-aware

Comment: Not via the available fullCalendar settings no - otherwise I would have mentioned in my answer. The only other way you could go is to make a fully [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js) of your own. But be warned that this is quite a time-consuming and complex tax, and you also then have to maintain it afterwards to ensure you stay compatible with future fullCalendar updates. I guess you could make the process easier by cloning the current dayGridMonth code and modifying it, but it will still be a lot of work - so you need to consider whether it brings enough benefit.